# Solution platform set to x86 but dll files at bin folder are loaded instead of bin/x86/debug

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm having a problem where I have set the solution platform to x86, but the dll files at bin folder are loaded instead of bin/x86/debug. Whenever i want to debug a web application, I have to copy the dll files and pdb files from bin/x86/debug to bin folder to enable the debug mode. Otherwise, it will show

> Breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols loaded for this
>   document.

I have been suffered from this issue since couple of weeks ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the build destination in the project properties.

Comment: the build destination is set to wrong directory. now its working. Thank